# Average calculation between three factors

Tags: sql-server, average

I need to calculate the average across the past 5 months(APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG). I have 2 splits to consider: Region(6 regions in total) and Status (between Build and Flow-thru). Currently the data is in a weekly format so I rounded up the weeks to get monthly figures. How do i get the average monthly figure using with the two splits. The table looks something like this:

```
Region|Orders|BuildStatus|Months
GP    |1     |Build      |APR
GP    |2     |Non-Build  |APR
GP    |1     |Build      |MAY
GP    |2     |Non-Build  |MAY
PD    |1     |Build      |APR
PD    |2     |Non-Build  |APR
PD    |1     |Build      |MAY
PD    |2     |Non-Build  |MAY
```

It repeats with 5 other regions up until August.

Please assist with the correct calculation and if possible you can also suggest the query for it.
The Result should be:

```
Region|Avg_Orders|BuildStatus
GP    |1         |Build
GP    |2         |Non-Build
PD    |1         |Build
PD    |2         |Non-Build
```

The figures on the average should be the average of the 5 months.

Thanks

Comment: `The table looks something like this` ... you lost me with the `Months` column.  _Never_ store dates as text, and in this case it isn't even something remotely close to an ISO date.  It will probably take a lot of SQL date acrobatics to answer your question.

Comment: Please focus on whats on the table. The data is already cooked and that is just the summary

Comment: OK...but you should at least show sample data from the original table and the expected output.  This tells us more than anything else.

Comment: Please check the questions. I made the requested changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  Region NVARCHAR(2)
 ,Orders INT
 ,BuildStatus NVARCHAR(100)
 ,Months NVARCHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('GP', 1,'Build',      'APR')
,('GP', 2,'Non-Build',  'APR')
,('GP', 1,'Build',      'MAY')
,('GP', 2,'Non-Build',  'MAY')
,('PD', 1,'Build',      'APR')
,('PD', 2,'Non-Build',  'APR')
,('PD', 1,'Build',      'MAY')
,('PD', 2,'Non-Build',  'MAY');


WITH cteAgg AS(
  SELECT t.Region, t.BuildStatus, SUM(t.Orders) Orders, COUNT(DISTINCT t.Months) MonthsCount
  FROM @t t
  GROUP BY t.Region, t.BuildStatus
)
SELECT Region, Orders/MonthsCount AS Avg_Orders, BuildStatus
  FROM cteAgg
  ORDER BY 1
```